# How to send request in JSON format using TTURLRequest?

Tags: ios, json, three20

I have recently suffered from a problem regarding TTURLRequest.

I have been using Three20 framework for several months and I know that there are two ways of sending requests using TTURLRequest.

1. Using url combined with parameters, such as `http://www.test.com/test?username=u&password=p`
2. Using build-in `parameter` property in NSMutableDictionary format and the parameters are set like this:

   `TTURLRequest *request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
   [request.parameter setObject:@"obj" forKey:@"o"];`

The problem for now is that I need to send a request with JSON format.

Is it possible to convert the `request.parameter` to a JSON format? Or, should I implement a JSON format property for TTURLRequest to send the request?

Comment: Are you using `TTURLRequest` by itself or part of three20? The three20 project appears to be no longer in development.

Comment: @ThomasW, part of three20, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd recommend you stop using Three20, because it is no longer supported or actively being developed. Of course, that doesn't answer your question.